# Evitar pantallas de error por manipulacion de barra de direcciones

Tags: php, laravel

me gustaria saber como evitar un error del tipo
 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 (o cualquier otro error que informe al usuario de lo que pasa en laravel) al introducir manualmente o intentar manipular la barra de direcciones poniendo algun texto o ruta no existente.
Sé que se puede poniendo el debug a false ocultas esta informacion, pero saldria la pantalla con el "Opps", la cual tampoco deberia salir al introducir algo que no existe en la barra de direcciones.
Sé que existen varios metodos para conseguir esto pero me gustaria saber cual es el mas usado y el mas efectivo.

Por si alguién ha llegado hasta aqui y no entiende aun lo que quiero decir pondré un ejemplo un poco mas representativo.

Tenemos esta ruta

http://localhost/ficheros/public/admin/catx/162/edit

y ha alguién le da por modificarla y poner algo asi

http://localhost/ficheros/public/admin/catx/162222222222222222/edit

en este caso saldria la pantalla con el Opps si el debug esta a false o con el NotFoundHttpException si el debug esta a true, lo que quiero saber es el mejor sistema para evitar que se muestren estas pantallas.

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso de laravel maneja paginas de error, ubicada el la carpeta **resources->views->errors**
Lo que deberias hacer es crear una nueva pagina dependiendo a tu código de estado

por ejemplo el codigo **405** el cual se refiere a la ruta no encontrada, ahi creas el archivo llamado **405.blade.php**.

Este es un codigo de ejemplo

**405.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ruta no encontrada.</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            color: #B0BEC5;
            display: table;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 72px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="title">Error 405. Ruta No Encontrada</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si bueno, eso en concreto lo sé, redireccionar todo a este tipo de paginas de error, lo que me hace falta es saber el codigo a implementar y como implementarlo para que al introducir una ruta no valida, redirija a estas a estas paginas. Si os habeis fijado no he puesto ningún codigo, puesto que el codigo que busco es mas bien general para todo tipo de projectos . Ahora mismo estoy leyendo en la documentacion de laravel "The Exception Handler", aunque no sé si habrá otro sistema. Te agradezco la respuesta.